# Google Analytics IP Filter Exclude

Tags: regex, google-analytics, analytics

Could someone help me with some REGEX...

I have been blocking internal traffic using the filter pattnrn:

10.*.*.*

This just bit me in the foot as this is blocking all referral traffic between our sites.

What I want to do now is block everything except 10.103.*.*

Do I need to apply two separate ranges, or can I accomplish this with one filter?

Comment: Everything? Why in hell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to block everything but `10.103.xxx.xxx`, use an **include** filter instead of the usual exclude filter.

[image: include filter GUI in Analytics]

## NOTE ABOUT REGEXES MATCHING IPs IN ANALYTICS

I am not sure if the filter I suggested above uses regex or not (literal string match), but it doesn't make a difference because there's no way the expression `10.103.` could be misinterpreted in an IP address.

**Your original pattern, on the other hand, is bogus and is probably hurting you.** That's because in a regex the dot `.` is not a literal dot, but represents any character. Your expression, in fact, excludes every single IP that merely **starts with 10** (not just `10.` that is ten-dot), including `100.xxx`, `101.xxx` etc.

The correct version of your original excluding regex would be `10\..*`, which contains an **escaped dot** (`\.`), then proceeds to any characters after that (`.*`).

Comment: Ill give this a shot. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

REGEXP are very good explained in the Google Analytics Help ([here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034324)).

For multiple IPs, there is this [little helper](http://www.analyticsmarket.com/freetools/ipregex), which generates the REGEXP for you.

If you want to block internal traffic, just ADD NEW FILTER and CUSTOM then EXCLUDE and put the IP in REGEXP in the field, that's it.